# How to Find Local Lowest Point(s) on a Landform?

Tags: python, raster, dem, digital-image-processing, topography

I am trying to write a code to find the local lowest points using Python. This approach will be applied to raster landform data such as digital elevation models. What approach can I take to find the lowest point(s) in a digital elevation model?

[image]

Comment: You could invert your image and find the local maxima using `scikit-image`. http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/plot_peak_local_max.html

Comment: Thanks for the information!  I wrote a code that checks whether a point is lower than its adjacent ones. It works but not very neat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can the Python bindings for [GDAL](http://www.gdal.org/) which are available through QGIS (if you have that installed already) or can be downloaded for standalone use [here](http://www.gisinternals.com/).

1. Either using [NUMPY](http://www.numpy.org/) or [SciPy](https://www.scipy.org/) (the latter is probably faster - numpy is available in the QGIS install), create a moving window to scan across each grid square and find those where all the surrounding cells are higher. To pin point the low spot more accurately (depending on the scale of your raster), interpolate across the low-point cell.  You can refine this process using Slope and Aspect (calculated using [GDALDEM](http://www.gdal.org/gdaldem.html)) to eliminate minor depressions.
2. OR: use GDALdem to calculate the topographic position index([TPI](https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdalogr/gdal_analysis.html)). This will do something similar to the above.  You will need to do a second pass to clearly differentiate between a valley/gully and an actual 'bottom', so I am not sure you gain much unless you are prepared to accept a 'fuzzy bottom' by taking x% of the lowest negative values.  If your data is as simple as above, this won't be an issue.  If it is complex terrain then you could miss some locations and at other locations have a couple of contiguous 'bottoms'.